# Font Awesome class mapped to angular import definitions

Tags: angular, font-awesome, angular-fontawesome

https://fontawesome.com/icons/

When searching for an icon it gives you the class to enter into the HTML, but angular requires to use the icondefinitions.

for example:

`<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i>`

Would be the following with angular:

`<fa-icon [icon]="['fas','star']"></fa-icon>`

How do I figure out the icondefinition for the icons I find in the website?

I have found the list of definitions in the project, but it doesn't really help mapping it to the icon on the site.

[List of icondefinitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kycYt.png)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you try to achieve. [findIconDefinition(params)](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/methods#findicondefinition-params)

Comment: Or may refer to this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d6azx4?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with `this.iconLibrary.getIconDefinition(/* prefix */, /* name */);`

Comment: The icon name should be the same, but using `faCamelCase` instead of the `fa-kebab-case`. And then you would import the definition from the [corresponding style package](https://github.com/FortAwesome/angular-fontawesome/blob/master/docs/usage/using-other-styles.md). Also, make sure you've selected the correct version in the icon search bar, because many icons were renamed in the FA 6 and you won't find them when using FA 5 icon packs.

Comment: The question is the identifier inside "['fas','???']". How do I know which one maps to the one I like in the website?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using the class directly "fa-solid fa-diamond".

I was pulling this from an data array and pulled it in via a variable like this:

```
<a class="{{data.icon}}"></a>
```

```
    {
        routeLink: '/tabletopcreator/dashboard',
        icon: "fa-solid fa-diamond",
        label: 'Tabletop Creator',
    }
```

This worked because i added this to the index.html

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/98f07d8644.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```